# Using REGEXP with where condition when paginating in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this search terms i am receiving from the user and i want to return some data which is finally being used to query mysql like this

This is how i am querying mysql `SELECT * FROM search_data WHERE index_desc REGEXP 'one|two'`

```
public function results()
{
    $searchterm = $this->input->post('searchterm');
    //echo clean($searchterm);
    $myst =  clean($searchterm);
    $myst = trim($myst);
    //Mysql REGEXP
    $search_keywords = str_replace(' ', '|', $myst);
   

   $config = array();
   $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "search/results";
   $config["total_rows"] = $this->Ion_auth_model->record_count();
   $config["per_page"] = 5;
   $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
   $this->pagination->initialize($config);
   $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
   $data["results"] = $this->Ion_auth_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page, $search_keywords);
   $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
   $this->load->view("results", $data);
}
```

This is the model function

```
    public function fetch_data($limit, $start,$search_keywords) {
       $where_string = 'REGEXP'.$search_keywords;
       $this->db->where('index_desc', $where_string );
       $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
       $query = $this->db->get("search_data");
       if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
           foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
               $data[] = $row;
           }
           return $data;
       }
       return false;
   }
```

This is where i am having a problem

```
$where_string = 'REGEXP'.$search_keywords;
$this->db->where('index_desc', $where_string );
```

since this is what i am expecting `SELECT * FROM search_data WHERE index_desc REGEXP 'one|two'` and i am not getting the results i want. How can i solve this problem?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a custom string in CI where() function like:

```
$where_string = "index_desc REGEXP '$search_keywords'";
$this->db->where($where_string );
```

see [Looking for specific data, last bullet (4)](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where#looking-for-specific-data)

Comment: The query is missing this ' ' after REGEXP on $search_keywords

Comment: I've updated, should include the `''` now

Comment: Also the where is repeated.